Safety considerations when measuring an analog signal across an isolation barrier
I'm designing a PCB that is powered by 230V AC and switches 5 heating elements via 5 Triacs. As a best practice I included optotriacs for driving the main triacs and used a 230V to 5V buck converter with a 5kV isolation barrier to power the micro controller.
However I would also like to measure the current of all the heaters via a shunt resistor. My first idea was to use multiple isolation amplifiers. But when seeing this circuit in the datasheet, especially a standard low-voltage TPS76350 LDO on the high voltage side, I began to wonder.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1400.pdf
If it is valid to put a single low voltage component on the high voltage side why not more of them? It would reduce cost and component count if I placed a standard non-isolated OpAmp and a SPI ADC on the HV side and just used a SPI signal isolator across the isolation barrier (e.g. ISO674x).
But if that is also valid what is the limit of components I can put on the HV side? Couldn't I just leave out the isolation barrier all together then? I came to the following conclusion:
What purpose has the isolation barrier?

reduce likelihood of fire hazards
reduce likelihood of (silent) component failure e.g. triac not switched off when it should
protect external devices that expect low voltage at a connector on the low voltage side
protection of the user? (when fully enclosed in earthed housing and connectors are protected I see no safety advantage for the user)

Will these protection goals also be fulfilled with ADC and OpAmp on the HV side?

as long as there is enough spacing around the components (so HV can not arc over) fire hazards are equally as likely but when over voltage enters via trace more components are affected
same for component failures
safety of external devices is not compromised as long as the LV components on the HV side sit behind a DC/DC isolation transformer
user safety will not be compromised directly

So in my eyes this design choice will be fine and I could even put a whole complex circuit on the HV side as long as a safe spark distance is kept and all HV potentially coming thru the trace can not reach external connectors or safety critical parts e.g. the main micro controller.
Is this reasoning valid? Have I forgotten any safety aspect of the isolation barrier?

Besides buttons and LEDs, are there any user accessible interfaces towards the MCU?

@winny There is user button, a user led, a  USB C Port and 4 Ports for temperature sensors connected.


What is the purpose of the isolation barrier?

reduce likelihood of fire hazards


No


reduce likelihood of (silent) component failure e.g. triac not switched off when it should


Definitely not


protect external devices that expect low voltage at a connector on the low voltage side


Yes


protection of the user? (when fully enclosed in earthed housing and connectors are protected I see no safety advantage for the user)


If there are any switches, LEDs etc. they can be 'hot', which may mean increased costs and complexity for the same protection.

Personally, I would look into using a current transformer rather than a shunt resistor, which would provide isolation and would not be at risk of damage if a short occurs.

Anyway, you can put parts on either side of an isolation barrier. It's quite reasonable to have an MCU on the hot side and have unidirectional or bidirectional digital communication across the barrier. There's a bit more work in coming up with the protocol, and writing and maintaining another bit of code, but that's a pretty small job typically in the greater scheme of things.
If there are user controls and indicators it may make more sense to put them on the 'safe' side. If you have something like a USB connector or a debug connector or a programming port they should be on the safe side.

Why are fire hazards and components failures not reduced by an isolation barrier? I mean when more than the expected voltage enters a component either via spark or trace it may either burn down or fail partly/in an unexpected way or both.

You're adding components (and ones that are stressed) so there are more parts to fail. The triac failing won't be helped by having the control circuitry isolated- it will still be dead and whatever bad consequences there are will still occur. If the circuits are equally well designed there should be negligible risk of fire.

Ok, I understand. The isolation will only help as a second protection layer, after the Triac itself got damaged, which should not happen when the circuit is well designed.
But if you view the pure physical distance of HV to LV components also as "isolation" it will actually reduce the fire risk, as a spark caused from inrush HV (which might not damage e.g. the triac) might still burn something on the LV side.

Generally triacs fail shorted and typically they fail because of something from the outside such as a lightning strike or a short circuit or a failure of a cooling fan. They are almost impossible to economically protect because they are very fragile compared to electromechanical things like switches and ordinary fuses. Transients on the mains can be severe- things like lightning storms, for example. Protecting the driving circuit from any kind of failure at the triac (including an open gate-MT1), even without isolation is not difficult.


Couldn't I just leave out the isolation barrier all together then?

We use isolation barriers for the reasons that Spehro mentions but, we also use them because you can never guarantee that what you think is the neutral (N) connection from the AC isn't actually live (L). Think about the problem if L and N got swapped and you didn't use an isolation barrier.

It would reduce cost and component count if I placed a standard
non-isolated op-amp and a SPI ADC on the HV side and just used a SPI
signal isolator across the isolation barrier (e.g. ISO674x).

That's the route that I prefer to go.

What would happen if L and N got switched? To my understanding the triac would not switch correctly anymore as it is not symmetrical and maybe the attached load would get damaged. But how does an isolation barrier help with this?

It's a triac and switches on either polarity of AC voltage. That has nothing to do with what I'm saying @DreiDe

What do you consider as "no isolation barrier" than? For me no isolation barrier just means not using optocouplers/isolators and having HV and LV components close together. I did not anticipate to connect GND and N together.

This question has been answered and accepted. If you want to ask new questions make a new post.
